# Partial check in

Tags: tfs, checkin

We are having problem with 'check in'. Is there any way to check in some changes in a file and leaving behind other changes.Because we want test some changes only. I know we can exclude some changed files for check in. But is there any way to exclude some changes in single file and check in other changes in same file??

Comment: A better way is to break up the work into smaller tasks that you can check in independently - with unit tests. You could Shelve your files and check in partially. I think partial checkins will lead to broken builds.

Comment: Consider that you can't do a "partial build". You don't want to check in anything that you can't build and test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, TFS forces all changes in a file to be checked in at the same time. There is no way to check in "only some" changes for a given file. Git does have some support for this but it is complicated. If you decide to use Git, TFS has a tool called git-tf that allows you to integrate between the two systems.